# DOMDocument parsing (php)

Tags: php, xml, parsing, domdocument

I am parsing an xml file from an API which I have converted into a DOMDocument in php. This is mostly fine but one problem I have is when I do this:

```
$feeditem->getElementsByTagName('extra');
```

as part of a forall statment and the element extra doesn't exist in one of the feeditems I am iterating through in the forall condition then I get an error.

I tried this:

```
if (!empty($feeditem->getElementsByTagName('extra'))){
$extratag = $feeditem->getElementsByTagName('extra');
    $extraname = $extratag->item(0)->getAttribute('name');
echo $extraname
    }
```

But I get the error

```
getAttribute() on a non-object
```

Note: When the 'extra' element is contained in every feeditem then the code runs perfect. it's just when one of the feed items doesn't contain an 'extra' element I get the error.

Comment: Sorry i meant as a foreach statement on the fourth line there

Comment: Can you update (edit) your post to reflect correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do use `length` property of [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php):

```
$nodes = $feeditem->getElementsByTagName('extra');
if ($nodes->length > 0) {
    $extraname = $extratag->item(0)->getAttribute('name');
}
```

Comment: you don't really need the `>0` check, but this will do what you want.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Been stuck on it since yesterday!

Works!

Comment: @meder do you khow why sometimes I get non-object error but the object is exists in xml?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096972/how-to-parse-xml-with-php-domdocument-and-be-sure-to-get-objects/18097678?noredirect=1#18097678

Comment: No, I think you should post this problem as separate question