# How to parse xml namespaces with DOMDocument and be sure to get objects

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument, php-5.3

I'm trying to parse a xml response from other server.

I can get my needed objects from that xml. but some times and some how, I cant get some objects. and this error appears.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in line 91

I checked every thing and I think there is nothing wrong.

here is an example xml response:

```
 <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
<response xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
    <result code="1000">
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
    </result>
    <resData xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
        <domain:infData xmlns:domain="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0">
            <domain:name>pooyaos.ir</domain:name>
                <domain:roid>305567</domain:roid>
                <domain:status s="serverHold"/>
                <domain:status s="irnicReserved"/>
                <domain:status s="serverRenewProhibited"/>
                <domain:status s="serverDeleteProhibited"/>
                <domain:status s="irnicRegistrationDocRequired"/>
                <domain:contact type="holder">pe59-irnic</domain:contact>
                <domain:contact type="admin">pe59-irnic</domain:contact>
.
.
and more...
```

and I am trying to get this object `domain:infData`

I think the error is from this part.

when I am trying to get this object, domdocument returns null.

php code:

```
function DinfData()
    {
        $data = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName("infData")->item(0);

91:     $name = $data->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $roid = $data->getElementsByTagName("roid")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $update = $data->getElementsByTagName("upDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $crdate = $data->getElementsByTagName("crDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $exdate = $data->getElementsByTagName("exDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;

and more...
```

I marked line 91 in error.

thanks ....

## edit

`$this->dom` is my DOMDocument object and has no error.

If nothing is wrong is there any better way to get elements?

Comment: Show your result in $data = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName("infData")->item(0);

Comment: what is your feed url. give me i will guide you

Comment: @NathanSrivi it is a null object...

Comment: you cant use url. your server ip has to register in the site. http://epp.nic.ir/

Comment: ok simply use my simplexml_load_file() function and give me the result. i will guide you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php) which is for use with namespaced elements. Find the namespace that `domain` points to and pass it to the method along with the target tag name e.g. `roid` or `name`.

[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/639Y8BsZ)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$ns = 'http://epp.nic.ir/ns/domain-1.0';

$data = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'infData')->item(0);

$roid = $data->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'roid')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$name = $data->getElementsByTagNameNS($ns, 'name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
// repeat the same for others

echo $roid . "\n";
echo $name;
```

Outputs

```
305567
pooyaos.ir
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply put in your url into simple_load_file()

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
print $xml->infData;   // Sample content
?>
```

This is a easiest method

Comment: @Pooya this is a easy method to use

Answer (score -1):

But infData is not your tagName. This XML uses namespaces (domain is your namespace). Don't have experience with that so I really can help you any futher then the hint where to look. The getElementsByTagName is not going to work, you need something like DOMXPath I think that's where you can do something with namespaces.

Sorry I can't be of futher help but since no one mentioned the namespaces I thought I would just add the answer anyway. Maybe it will help you Google for an answer.

Comment: getElementsByTagName() was very useful for me, but Rarely (just in this case) I receive unexpected error.